# Points disappearing after pasting symbology from another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, style, comparison

I am planning to plot some graduated points, based on their value, while also keeping the scale the same for different parameters. Naturally, I imported the CSV file that included the points. Upon plotting as categorized points, I set the value for the corresponding parameters, as you can see in the screenshots;

[image: these are the settings that I used in plotting model salinity]

[image: and menu for satellite salinity]

The points were automatically classified in 8 classes for both cases and these returned me with the following plots:

[image]
[image]

Since I want to compare these two parameters on the same scale, I copied the symbology from the `Sal_Sat` layer and pasted it upon `SS_Model-Bias` then changed the `SS_Model-Bias` layer's value to its original parameters which looked something like this:

[image]

Applying one layer's symbology to another, made some points disappear which was visible in the earlier classifications.
[image]

What is causing the points to disappear after symbology of another layer of different style is being pasted on it?

I am using QGIS 3.16 LTR.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you examine the value ranges for two layers, you will see that any one doesn't completely cover the other. `Sal_Sat` ranges between `-2 - 3.9`, `SS_Model-Bias` ranges between `-0.66 - 7.6`. When you copy `Sal_Sat` upon `SS_Model-Bias`, you lose the features whose values are bigger than `3.9`. This case is clearly seen in the final map. There is no value that is bigger than `3.9`.

A solution for this is to add more style layers manually to the symbology of `SS_Model-Bias` layer, animated as follows:

[image]